# Finding Range Between Values and Setting States

Tags: javascript, lodash, web-audio-api

I'm currently creating an application that uses Binaural Beats/plays different frequencies in each ear. Here's what I'm working with:

```
var frequency = {
    "Gamma": [30, 50],
    "Beta": [14, 30],
    "Alpha": [8, 14],
    "Theta": [4, 8],
    "Delta": [0.1, 4]
};
```

The way Binaural Beats work is that the difference between the frequency played in the left ear and right ear should be equivalent to the values in the array. For example, a Gamma Wave Binaural Beat would have the difference between frequencies be 30 - 50 as shown in the object/array.

I'm currently using sliders and text boxes to set the frequencies played. How would I be able to dynamically set the state (Gamma, Beta, Alpha, etc.) by checking the values between frequencies without it being clunky? I've tried using [_inRange](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.0#inRange) in Lodash but still can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can you add to the question - What is the expected result? Do you want to know if all selections are in range? Do you want to find one who don't? How does the entry data looks like? Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Uh sure, here's my Gist: https://gist.github.com/JelaniThompson/cdde9207a963a5d6db0046d0643532b3

Comment: Where I'm using Vue at the bottom, I want to dynamically update the title and description based on the range between the values :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your logic, you need to find if the difference between left and right falls inside one of the ranges:

```js
var frequency = {
  "Gamma": [30, 50],
  "Beta": [14, 30],
  "Alpha": [8, 14],
  "Theta": [4, 8],
  "Delta": [0.1, 4]
};

var freqs = ['Delta', 'Theta', 'Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma']; // array of frequencies from the lowset to the highest range

function findFrequency(left, right) {
  return _.find(freqs, function(value) { // find the frequnecy
    var range = frequency[value]; // take the range from the frequency array
    var diff = Math.abs(left - right); // get the diff btween right to left
    return _.inRange(diff, range[0], range[1]); // find if the diff is in the range
  });
}

var result = findFrequency(3, 32);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```